# python unittest iterate a list of mobile devices doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-chromedriver

I need to perform the same test taking a list of mobile devices.
I am using subtest but the setting of each device does not work correctly.
Any ideas or can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

```
class test_CP03V3(unittest.TestCase):

def test_CP03V3(self):
    #Abre excel modelos
    archivoX = pd.read_excel("celulares.xlsx")
    df = pd.DataFrame(archivoX)

    for i in df.index:
        with self.subTest(msg=df['Etiqueta'][i]):

            #SETEO PANTALLA CELULAR
            mobileEmulation = {"deviceMetrics": {"width": int(df['Width'][i]), "height": int(df['Height'][i]),
                                                 "pixelRatio": float(df['pixelRatio'][i])},
                               "userAgent": str(df['userAgent'][i])}
            options = Options()
            if df['Etiqueta'][i] != 'desktop':
                options.add_experimental_option('mobileEmulation', mobileEmulation)
            else:
                options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)


            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            self.verificationErrors = []
            self.accept_next_alert = True
            driver = self.driver
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
```